# numerals charcode convert into another language numerals

Tags: javascript, localization

I want to convert numerals into other language numerals, how can I do this?

I want to be able to support as many languages as possible (google translation supported languages). I've been reading and I believe this can be done from charcode.

Here is some code I copied from some Javascript application, but it only supports 2 languages.

```
TextTools.arabicNumber = function (str) {
    var res = String(str).replace(/([0-9])/g, function (s, n, ofs, all) {
        return String.fromCharCode(0x0660 + n * 1);
    });
    return res;
}
TextTools.farsiNumber = function (str) {
    var res = String(str).replace(/([0-9])/g, function (s, n, ofs, all) {
        return String.fromCharCode(0x06F0 + n * 1);
    });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've basically solved the problem already, you just need to look at the Unicode standard to find where the other numeral characters exist.  You can check out [Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) or just use [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) for the character ranges.  Some interesting things to note, though:

Not every language/culture uses a decimal positional number system, although most extant ones do.  You'll want to verify that the number symbols are used the same way as they are in the West to be sure you've got it correct.  For all I know, Japanese or Korean numbers are written out using a different system but they use Western numbers in other contexts the same way the West does.  You'll need to verify all this to ensure you've got a correctly working system.

But from a technical translation point-of-view, assuming you're just going to convert Western numerals to numerals in another script, you've got it figured out.

**ETA:**  In reference to a comment, consider the case of [traditional Hebrew numbers](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew-numbers.html).  Numbers are formed as units + tens + hundreds (actually hundreds + tens + units when reading right-to-left).  So 456 becomes 400 + 50 + 6, or in Hebrew, תנו.

Comment: no this is not my code, i got it from some other website and added here for example usage. ok lets say i want to add hebrew numbers, how can i do that from that code chart you gave?

Comment: Check out this link http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew-numbers.html .  It seems traditional hebrew numbers are not positional but additive, so you build them up like you would Roman numerals.  Modern Hebrew numbers are done using the Western digits.

Comment: one last thing. the code charts link you provided, its mostly letters. can you provide different link of code chart, that gives numbers too for the most of the languages available.

Comment: Also remember in a large number of European languages have the opposite meaning for '.' and ',' so a number in English 1,123,456.12 would be 1.123.456,12 in French, Italian or Spanish

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there's going to be a general solution for lots of languages. I don't have a good understanding, but as people have pointed out in the Hebrew discussion, if the characters are different, the ordering or interpretation is probably different. As you learned in grade school, there's a simple translation to Roman numerals, but it's not just a character-to-character transformation. I think you'll need to target specific languages, and consult an expert (or wikipedia) to build out code for each.

I thought maybe google translate would know how to do this, but it looks like they don't from a [quick check](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=512&langpair=en%7Ciw&langpair=en%7Czh). Correct me if I'm wrong.

But for the ones that are just transliterations, here are unicode numbers for an assortment of languages: [roman numerals](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/roman.num/), [Tamil](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/tamil.digit/), [Arabic](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/arabic.indic.digit/), [Devanagari](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/devanagari.digit/), [Bengali](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/bengali.digit/), [Gurmukhi](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/gurmukhi.digit/), [Gujarati](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/gujarati.digit/), [Thai](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/thai.digit/), [Tibetan](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/tibetan.digit/), [Mongolian](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/mongolian.digit/), [Hangzhou](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=/hangzhou.numer/), etc. It's easy to find more using this utility I wrote.

Comment: ya google dont translate numbers, else we didnt head to worry about writing our own. btw your utility is really good, i really like it. just one thing tho, how can i find the complete list of supported languages, so i can look into them too.. i tried typing arabic that didnt work, they need special uniqe name for it to show up, so im wondering where is the complete list of the names.